# HTTPS Just won’t render CSS

Tags: php

I’ve spent about 3 days troubleshooting my site. I can’t get it to display the CSS. I’ve tried everything different posts have recommended. Plugins, site, home url, search and replace but nothing. I have SSL certificates from an AWS Load balancer. The url is https://kingtest2.sprintersinsurance.com . HTTP works fine . Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the console? see what the path is under network for css/js. maybe you misspelled the file name, maybe you have a extra `/` somewhere. The link doesn't work so its imposible to know exactly what the problem is

Comment: Corrected url: https://kingtest2.sprintersinsurance.com thanks

Comment: My guess is the you site url still has http:// instead of https://, in phpmyadmin under the `wp_options` (if the prefix is `wp_`) the first 2 rows, are they with `https://`?

Comment: I’ve changed it to https and it just locks me out of the admin area and the site looks the same.

Comment: Are you sure the ssl is installed for the correct domain/subdomain? check with your hosting, they can help. Also, if you can, add the code from the `wp_enqueue_scripts`, maybe something there is missing as well

Comment: I’ve got it set up using an AWS load balancer. It’s weird that the css just won’t render.

Comment: @davefogo, that happens because of what is called "active mixed content" - see [this](https://web.dev/what-is-mixed-content/) or just search on Google. So you can try [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) or [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) plugin, but you really should [change your site URL](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/) setting to use the secure protocol (`https`).

Comment: @SallyCJ using the SSL insecure content fixed it! I’d tried all but this one! Thanks so much.